# Limit the Number of Characters with Regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have the below `read` that will take a username in the form of `first.last`.  This is handled by the regex below.  How can I limit the maximum amount of characters to `16`?

I have tried adding `^[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+{,16}$` but when testing, allowed me to create a password > 16 chars

```
read -p "Enter a Username (firstname.lastname): " username
until [[ "${username}" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$ ]];
do
        read -p "Incorrect format, retry Username: " username
done
```

The outcome would be for there to be a limit of 16 characters applied to the `read` for the username.

**Edit**

I managed to get it working with a none-regex solution as I originally wanted, see below:

```
read -p "Enter a Username (first.last): " username

until [[ "${username}" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$ ]] && (( 
"${#username}" < 16 )); do
    read -p "Maximum of 16 characters, try again: " username
done
```

**Outputs:**

*Good:*

```
bash -x userInt.sh
+ read -p 'Enter a Username (first.last): ' username
Enter a Username (first.last): foo.bar
+ [[ foo.bar =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]
+ ((  7 < 16  ))
+ read -sp 'Enter a Password (Minimum 8 characters): ' password
```

*Bad:*

```
bash -x userInt.sh
+ read -p 'Enter a Username (first.last): ' username
Enter a Username (first.last): someones.reallylongname
+ [[ someones.reallylongname =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]
+ ((  23 < 16  ))
+ read -p 'Maximum of 16 characters, try again: ' username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your users are going to hate you if "incorrect format" is all the info you give them. Second, you're asking a lot of one regex. Yes, you might be able to *do* it with a regex, but have some pity of the guy maintaining it behind you. :)

I'll assume you are simply disallowing all non-alphas. You sure you don't want to automatically downcase it too? And as an aside, this will disallow extended characters, and firstname.lastname is a very euro-centric mindset...

```
declare -l username # forces values to lowercase
msg="Please use only letters with a single dot separator, and limit the total to 16 characters."
while read -p "Enter a Username (firstname.lastname): " username
do case "$username" in                                # check for
   # too long  | invalid chars | multidots
   ?????????????????*|*[^a-z.]*|*.*.*) echo "$msg" ;; # add A-Z if not downcasing
   *.*) break;;                                       # this is the format we want
   *) echo "$msg" ;;                                  # a catch-all in case we missed anything else
   esac
done
```

Regexes are more powerful than globbing, but this is more readable to me. YMMV.

Comment: Nice!  Yes, the error messages need improving :).  Also, you're missing an `esac` before your `done` for the case statement, other than that, seems to work just fine @Paul.

Answer (score 1):

You did not write your if the 16 characters should be a limitation for both or each of the first or last name.

If you want a limitation for each 16 characters you can do it the following way:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,16}\.[a-zA-Z]{1,16}$
```

If it should be an overall limit then you can do it like this (excluding the dot from the count):

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,8}\.[a-zA-Z]{1,8}$
```

**First edit:**
I did not include the bash code (based on your question):

```
read -p "Enter a first name (firstname.lastname): " username
until [[ "${username}" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]{1,8}\.[a-zA-Z]{1,8}$ ]];
do
        read -p "Incorrect format, retry Username: " username;
done
```

This would impose a limit of 8 characters on both first and last name.  As I have suggested in the comment you should make a first/last name length statistics and adjust the limits based on it.

Comment: Using the above regex, I ran the following tests:

`Enter a Username (firstname.lastname): qwertyu.asdfghjk # 16 chars
Maximum of 16 characters, try again: qwertyu.asdfghj # 15 chars
Maximum of 16 characters, try again: qwertyu.asdfgh # 14 chars`

None of which workes, modified code:

`read -p "Enter a Username (firstname.lastname): " username
until [[ "${username}" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]{1,16}$ ]];`

Comment: There isn't going to be a nice way to do this.  `mysql.user` has a character limit of 16 for `user` (the above is creating a user for MySQL) so limiting `firstname` to `{1,8}` and `lastname ` to `{1,8}` is not ideal if you have a really long `firstname` for example.  The first example 'could' allow a username to be a total of up to 32 chars, right?

Comment: @sudodashell Yes, the first one would be 32 characters. You are right there won't be a pretty solution for this one.  You could, theoretically, split first/last name entry and then count it but the issue is that if someone enters 10 characters long first name then you are left with 6 characters for the last name which is probably not enough.  How would I approach it?  I would take an average from the names that I have and then I would impose the limits to fit it.