# Way for regex with read

Tags: bash

I am trying to catch only names starting from"d" with a length 3 to 5 letters in one line:

Currently, I have this line in my script which works for each provided user name:

```
read -p "Enter user: " user
```

For example, is it possible to use a regex after the user? Example:

```
read -p "Enter user: " user | grep $user =~ "(d\w{3,5})"
```

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458802/limit-the-number-of-characters-with-regex) but does not tell me if it is possible.

Comment: `read` doesn't return a value or write what is read to standard output. It *just* sets the value of the variable(s) named by its argument(s). You can check the value of `user` *after* `read` completes, in a separate command.

Comment: When you say "3 to 5 letters" can you clarify the definition of `letters` whether it's A-Z or that it includes numbers and symbols? I've assumed the former, but, I can see chepner has assumed the latter. Also, clarify whether the query is case-sensitive. Did you want to only support lower case characters, and/or is the starting letter a lowercase "d"?

Comment: Only from A-Z for the whole name but written in lowercase so in fact a-z so it should catch names like denis, dolph etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the regex to `^d[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$` which consists of:

- `^d` - line must START with a lowercase "d"
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,4}` - there must be 2-4 letters after the "d" and can be in either lowercase or uppercase, numbers or symbols not permitted
- `$` - reject any trailing characters

```bash
read -p "Enter user: " user
while ! [[ $user =~ ^d[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$ ]]; do
    echo "Only names starting with "d" with a total length of 3 to 5 letters"
    read -p "Enter user: " user
done
```

Comment: I'm afraid that not all regex implementation are equal. You question says it must start with d. If that is not the case then use ^[a-zA-Z]{3,5}$

Answer (score 4):

After the value of `user` is set, you can examine its value.

```
 read -p "Enter user: " user
 if [[ $user =~ ^.{3,5}$ ]]; then
   echo "user between 3 and 5 characters"
 fi
```

The regular expression is not implicitly anchored to either end of the string, so you need to use `^` and `$` to check that the *entire* string is 3-5 characters, not just that the string as a *substring* of 3-5 characters.

In this case, you don't even need a regular expression.

```
if (( 3 <= ${#user} && ${#user} <=5 )); then
    ...
fi
```